# Hyper link to email address

Tags: c#, wpf, email, hyperlink

I'm try to use this code for open the email client (Outlook or Gmail, depending on user preference).

XAML:

```
    <TextBlock  Margin="0,5,0,0"  >
         <Hyperlink  RequestNavigate="HandleRequestNavigate" Foreground="{StaticResource EnableColorSolid}" NavigateUri="http://info@kramerel.com">
                   info@kramerel.com
         </Hyperlink>
    </TextBlock>
```

Code:

```
 private void HandleRequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
    {
        string navigateUri = (sender as Hyperlink).NavigateUri.ToString();
        // if the URI somehow came from an untrusted source, make sure to
        // validate it before calling Process.Start(), e.g. check to see
        // the scheme is HTTP, etc.
        Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(navigateUri));
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

But it's not working. Any idea why? I think there's a problem with the link, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Use "mailto:" instead of "http://"

Answer (score 1):

Use a `mailto` link:

```
<TextBlock  Margin="0,5,0,0"  >
         <Hyperlink  RequestNavigate="HandleRequestNavigate" 
          Foreground="{StaticResource EnableColorSolid}" 
          NavigateUri="mailto:info@kramerel.com">
                   info@kramerel.com
         </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: This will only work with the default email application.  If you want to use Gmail or any other web email provider, you'll have to use the `System.Net.Mail` namespace to send email via SMTP.  You could click the hyperlink, handle the navigation, then call your email function...